# Benchmarking Compact Cache v1 using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cache, benchmark

I'm trying to benchmark the read performance of different cache types. One of the cache types I am benchmarking is the ESRI Compact Cache v1.

If there is not a function in the ArcPy library which can read in a single tile from a compact cache, given x, y, and z coordinates, does Esri provide a lower level library for such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As [@AlexTereshenkov commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236893/accessing-specific-tile-from-compact-cache-v1-with-arcpy#comment369140_236893):

> Why would you use arcpy for benchmarking how fast one can read cache
> tiles? You won't be using arcpy to serve your tiles; you will be using
> either ArcMap when it is, for instance, a tiled package (.tpk) or
> ArcGIS Server / Runtime when serving ArcGIS Server map service cache.

To do this I think you will need to look to ArcObjects.